# ReactJS Search input by multiple values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a *search* and *select* filters on my page. The issue that I am having is that I can't seem to make the search work with multiple json values.

Example value is `{ "id": "1", "role": "teacher", "subject": "mathematics", "name": "Jonathan Kovinski" }` and I want to be able to use key and values.

I've tried using some other question about combining json *key* and *value* into a single array and passing it to the search filter but it didn't work.

```
text = data.filter(info => {
  return Object.keys(info).map(function(key) {
    var singleOne = JSON.stringify(info[key]);
    console.log(info, "This is the json one")
  }).toLowerCase().match(searchString);
});
```

Here is a link to a [JS Fiddle that I've created](https://jsfiddle.net/jn420hby/14/) with all of my code.

> I am trying to set my search bar to use all keys and values for searching and sorting data.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? Are you getting _any_ output? At a glance, you're calling `.toLowerCase()` on the array output by `Object.keys().map()` so that's going to give you an error.

Comment: @imjared I am getting output whenever I use the code provided in the JS Fiddle but I can only search by a given json key. As I said, I am trying to search by all keys and values.

"What doesn't work", my attempt to make it work with all values and keys. If you can try and help me adjust my code to use the `Object.key(info).map` function

Comment: Look into other array methods, like `find`, `some`, `every`, `includes`

Comment: @nem035 I am not exactly sure how to do this. Is the map function not appropriate for what I am trying to do ?

Comment: You could also use Object.entries() to combine the kevs and values into a common array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest you put the `filtered` data in a seperate key in the state in case you want to revert to the original result,
use the `Obeject.values` instead of `Object.keys` and filter the `data` in the `handleChange` function,

[here's a working code](https://jsfiddle.net/rudp3knz/) :

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      data: [],
      searchString: "",
      filtered: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    var value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      searchString: value,
      filtered: this.state.data.filter(e =>
        Object.values(e)
          .join(" ")
          .toLowerCase()
          .match(value)
      )
    });
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/lo3ls")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          data: json,
          filtered: json
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log("parsing failed", error));
  }

  render() {
    var { isLoaded, data } = this.state;
    const searchString = this.state.searchString.trim().toLowerCase();
    let text = this.state.data;
    console.log(text);
    if (searchString.length > 0) {
      text = text.filter(info => {
        return info.role.toLowerCase().match(searchString);
      });
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="searchbar"
          value={this.state.searchString}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="Search"
          name="device"
        />

        <select className="category-select" name="categories" onChange={this.handleChange}>
          {data.map(info => (
            <option value={info.role}>{info.role}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
        {/* map through the filtered ones*/}
        {this.state.filtered.map(info => (
          <div className="display">
            <span className="role">Role: {info.role}</span>
            <span> Name: {info.name}</span>
            <span>, Subject: {info.subject}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I read all of your code in Fiddle, But I proffer [Fuse](http://fusejs.io/) to you. Use it inside your code in `componentDidMount` and implement your search. it is very easy and handy.

```
const options = {
  shouldSort: true,
  threshold: 0.6,
  location: 0,
  distance: 100,
  maxPatternLength: 32,
  minMatchCharLength: 1,
  keys: [
    "title",
    "author.firstName"
  ]
};

const fuse = new Fuse(list, options); // "list" is the item array
const result = fuse.search(""); // put your string inside double quotation
```

The `result` is your answer.